# Alt+Left mouse to orbit, while "pick with left mouse button" is enabled?

Tags: shortcut

A tough nut I guess. I am trying to make controls similar to Unity and Substance, but I can't make this happen. I can either have Alt+LMB orbiting OR LMB selection. Is there a way to have both?

Comment: Trying to do the same, i'm going between unity and blender too much.
I need ALT+Left mouse button got orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 2020 and Blender 2.83 allows me to select Edit --> Preferences --> Input --> Mouse --> Emulate 3 Button Mouse and that disables the mouse middle mouse button and I can orbit with Alt+left whilst still selecting with the left button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a best addon blender sensei download [here](https://blendersensei.com/store/#senseiformat)

In this addon there are much of shortcut and much easy to use.
There are various tutorial in the webpage how to install and use.

Note : In this addon blender will work as a normal but the shortcut and display view change.